# Adjusting text outline spacing in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm trying to adjust the spacing of my outline(shadow) text.

This is what I did:

{ Select Inner White of one of the Letters
EDIT, COPY.
EDIT, PASTE IN BACK.
Hold SHIFT Key and ARROW DOWN and ARROW RIGHT }

But, when I go to move the text. The first click moves it much further than desired.
I tried manually moving it, but my hands aren't that steady and makes it worse.

Is there a way to lessen the amount that's set by default?

Answer (score 1):

From the menu... `Illustrator > Preferences > General` and reduce the `Keyboard increment` amount. I set mine at 0.25pts so that every tap of the arrow keys is .25pts, but you can go as low as 0.01pts.